# Coating of IN-3 Nixie tubes

Tags: nixie

I'm thinking about buying some IN-3 nixie tubes for projects I have in mind.

Based on pictures available, some of them look like normal, clear glass tubes, some look like the glass is dark brown.

Is that some kind of coating that can be removed (if yes, how?), or is the glass just dark?

[image: photo of darkened tube]

Comment: you edit your own question as required... other people edit questions to correct spelling and formatting ... the picture belongs in you question, not in a comment

Comment: the picture shows a neon lamp that is basically  at the end of its  life

Comment: I didn't edit out 50% of my original question. And the picture shows brand new lamp. They look like this out of the box.

Comment: @ŁukaszSmoła it was me who edited your question; you can see that in the question's edit history actually, including my edit message! The idea was that I'm removing redundant information from your question. Obviously, you're asking a question about some topic and hope that people that are experienced with the specifics of that topic reply. However, you do not get to pick who replies – especially because there's probably **very** few people familiar with any specific Nixie tube. That's just obsolete technology, and while we do have a lot of hobbyists and ahem long-term humans here, you're

Comment: unlikely to ever meet someone on here that can remember working with any specific tube, unless that tube was extremely common.

Comment: Anyways, what you show has two contacts,meaning that it cannot be a Nixie tube. It might be a neon lamp?

Comment: @ŁukaszSmoła - Hi, To correctly [reference](/help/referencing) the image which is now in the question (copied from your comment), we need to add the link to the original *web page*. To try to help, I searched and found what I *think* was (or could have been) the source eBay page [here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/332834527189). Please confirm that was your source, or supply your source link, if different. TY

Answer (score 1):

> Is that some kind of coating that can be removed

Every coating can be removed with enough money put into the effort. Is it practical? Not at all.

The tubes you show are just worn out. If you get a brand new neon tube without the metal deposit on the inside of the glass, and drive it with high current for 5-10 minutes, you'll get the same coating, just perhaps less of it. Driving these tubes really hot - so that the glass is at say 200-300C - will cause this metal to deposit even faster.

Why would someone be selling them like it? Well, if there are buyers, there are usually sellers.

> The picture shows brand new lamp. They look like this out of the box.

When I'm selling a used smartphone on eBay, I usually put it back into its original box. It doesn't mean it's brand new. But it will sell for a better price even though it's listed truthfully as used and so on.

Same here. Used neon bulbs are for sale in a nice box where the replacements probably originally came from. With a пасспорт, bring nostalgia and retro vibes. The box ended up on the secondary market and now there will be potential buyers (ahem) who think that's how fresh neon bulbs look... and may even try to argue that point.

The sellers are laughing all the way to the bank probably?

Answer (score 0):

it's a coating on the inside, as far as I can see on your lamp there (it's not a Nixie tube, these have multiple cathodes, not at most one).

And it does look like these are lamps with a *getter* coating, i.e. some metallic film that is designed to absorb any non-inert gases that leak into the tube. But: the area seems too large to be proper, as they block the important part of the lamp. Or, this is a neon lamp after the end of its life, when the AC applied to its electrodes has finally managed to sputter the inner surface of the glass with electrode metal.

So, this might be a production defect, or pulled material from a large panel. I'd bet on the latter, because these kinds of things became obsolete all over the world when LEDs became available for control panel indicators; and that would very much fit my quality expectation for ebay neon lamps!

**UPDATE**: after seeing the [ebay offer this is most probably from](https://www.ebay.com/itm/332834527189), yes, these are end-of-life indicators pulled from an old soviet control panel or something. See how variable their degree of metal surface contamination is!

[image: Foto from ebay]

> And the picture shows brand new lamp.

That seems *extremely* unlikely, seeing the decades-old, dirty cardboard box they came from.

Comment: You may find this of interest: https://groups.io/g/neonixie-l/topic/in_3_neon_lamps/1044461?p= though they don't mention the metallization. From others I've seen, it may be gettering, or incidental to the production process.

Comment: my Cyrillic is rusty, but that datasheet is cute: "Passport for a miniature indicator IN-3"